# Invalid BitMapdata Error #2015

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, sprite, bitmapdata

```
        private static var tileDir:String;
        public static var tileImage:BitmapData;
        private static var loader:Loader;

        public static var tileReady:EventDispatcher = new EventDispatcher();
        public static var tileNum_perRow:Number = 3;
        public static var select:selector;

        public var tileNum:Number = 0;
        public var setBack:Number = 0;
        public var tileState:String;
        public var tCol:Number;
        public var tRow:Number;

        private var tWidth:int = 30;
        private var tHeight:int = 30;
        private var tImage:BitmapData;
        private var canvas:Bitmap;

        private var p:Point;
        private var r:Rectangle;    

        public function Tile():void
        {
            var tempImage:BitmapData = tileImage;
            r = new Rectangle(0,0,30,30);
            p = new Point(0,0);
            tImage = new BitmapData(30,30);
            tImage.copyPixels(tempImage,r,p);
        }
```

And I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: Error #2015: Invalid BitmapData.
```

It tends to happen when I copy the pixels. I dont know why.

```
tileImage;
```

tileImage is valid, I've used the variable in the code below and it works. But above doesnt. Don't know why. Anyone have any clues?

```
this.graphics.beginBitmapFill(tileImage);
this.graphics.drawRect(60, 0,tWidth ,tHeight );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figure a better solution

```
                theMatrix.translate(30,0);
        this.graphics.beginBitmapFill(tileImage,theMatrix);
        //this.graphics.drawRect(0, 0,tWidth ,tHeight );
        this.graphics.endFill();
```

using the theMatrix.translates give you the ability to choose what part of the tile you want, without effecting the position of the sprite